# Full Screen Control for Windows Phone 7 in Silverlight Media Framework

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, media, smf, mmppf

I am working to integrate SMF to our windows phone 7 project. But I can't find a fullscreen control. This is what videos are coming with full screen but I don't want this. I have a grid for video and want to make a button that clicked event has full screen command for video. How can I implement this?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Fullscreen" concept on the phone. Simply change the control so that it takes up the whole screen.
You could do this explicitly or, if you have size set to auto, just hide all other items on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 7 , there is an area called System Tray on the Top of the screen where the information related to Signal strength and the Battery Level is shown .

You cannot add any icons or text to this area , so there will be a empty space on the top of your Application.

However , if you dont want to have the empty space and instead if your Application needs be run in full screen mode , you can set the `SystemTray` visibility to false .

`SystemTray` is a static class defined in the namespace `Microsoft.Phone.Shell` and you can set its `IsVisible` to false

```
SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
```

Have a look [here](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/02/how-to-run-your-application-in-full-screen-mode-in-windows-phone-7/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/0eb78f76-8a25-4977-a550-9ea9a9193abc).